# Friend declaration for single member instead of whole class?

Tags: c++, oop, class, c++11, friend

Normally in C++ when class A declares friendship with class B, class B has full access to class A private members. What I need to do is to allow class B to access only one private member of class A and nothing else. Is there any way for it, maybe something new in C++11?

Comment: Extract (the declaration of) said one member into its own class, then make that class a parent of `A` and a `friend` of `B`? (Although at that point you could just code `B` to target said interface class and not really need the friendship.)

Comment: Inheritance can make this happen, because friendship is not inherited. However, you should try to find a solution that doesn't depend on friendship in the first place, because trying to use inheritance to fix issues with friends is going to end up getting complicated real quick.

Comment: A getter/setter function suffices !!!!

Comment: The thing is getter is too "public". Well it seems I will need to redesign it.

Comment: @user1873947 I submit you're stressing over access privileges too much. It's not a crime to control access to members using higher-level design elements.

Comment: Within a system (a group of related classes that work together to provide some functionality) I feel that exposing of privates is acceptable. The important thing is that the user of the _system_ (not of any 1 particular class in the system) have access to only a clear public interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of.  If it's really important to only allow access to a single member, you could wrap the data in another class (`C`) that has entirely private members, make that class a friend of `B` and provide a public accessor for the `C` object in `A`.

Something like this:

```
template<class T> class MatesWithB
{
     friend class B;

  public:
     MatesWithB( T & val ) : data(val) {}

  private:
     T& data;
     operator T&()             { return data; }
     operator const T&() const { return data; }
};

class A
{
      // ...
      MatesWithB<int> GetPrivateThingy() { return MatesWithB(thingy); }

   private:
      int thingy;            // Shared with class B
};
```

Something like that.  I haven't run this through a compiler to check.

But I just wonder...  When you find yourself needing to do this, isn't something in your design fundamentally flawed?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a GOOD reason to have a friend function in the first place, then I see nothing wrong with "trusting" the friend function to not touch other things than what it should touch.

Bear in mind that ANY function that has the address of your class [or can somehow get to the address] is able to modify the member variables should that function wish to do so. It may not be able to do it in a portable, future safe and reliable manner, but casting a pointer to a `char *` will be able to modify anything within a class that isn't nailed down by the operating system.

The point about `private`, `protected`, `public`, `friend`, etc is to allow the compiler to check that you are "obeying the contract" - but it can be overridden by "clever" programmers who are determined to do so. As part of this "contract" is that a `friend` class or function is allowed to touch anything in a the class it's a friend of. That's how it is. If you don't want that, then you shouldn't be declaring it a friend...